# How to perform two firebase database operation on different nodes in single request/function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am a `react-native developer` and new to firebase. I am performing firebase realtime database operation, have a look at code below;

```
firebase.database().ref('events/wedding/items').push(object).then((data) => {
    //success callback
    dispatch(addPendingInvoice({ ...invoice, id: data.key }))
    Alert.alert('Successfully added to Invoices', 'Please go to invoice section to clear first and continue.', [{ text: 'Ok' }])
}).catch((error) => {
    //error callback
    Alert.alert("Can't book package.", 'Please check your internet connection!', [{ text: 'OK', style: 'destructive' }])
})
```

Now, I wish to push another object to another node `events/wedding/packages` right after this firebase database function above. I can use another function inside then callback in above firebase functions. This is not a professional way to do this.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) method to "simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes". Note that "simultaneous updates made this way are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fails", see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

So in your case you would do along the following lines:

```
var newNodeKey = firebase.database().ref().child('events/wedding/items').push().key;

var updates = {};
updates['events/wedding/items/' + newNodeKey] = { foo: "bar" };
updates['events/wedding/packages/' + newNodeKey] = { bar: "foo" };

firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
    .then(() => {
        // The two writes are completed, do whatever you need
        // e.g. dispatch(...);

    });
```

Comment: Thank u so much brother! that reference was a mistake, nothing else.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll adapt the answer and remove `reference`.

Comment: With this update() function can we update one object on some route and push something to another route simultaniously?

Comment: I guess that by route you mean a path or reference. The answer is yes, you can write to two totally different references, like `updates['events/wedding/items' + newPostKey] = { foo: "bar" }; updates['abcd/efgh' + newPostKey] = { bar: "foo" };`

Answer (score 1):

All Firebase operations return a promise so you can use `Promise.all()` to run them all simultaneously.

```
Promise.all([
   firebase.database().ref(reference).set({}),
   firebase.database().ref(reference2).set({})
]).then(() => {
  console.log("Operations Successful")
}).catch((e) => console.log(e))
```

You can also push all your operations to an array and then pass that array in Promise.all()